# Make /xfce4 a synonym of /xfce?

Tags: support, tags

We have the tag [xfce4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xfce4) with 16 questions, and [xfce](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xfce) with 109 questions. They mostly refer to the same thing.

Can we have them merged or as synonyms (I don't have enough score in those tags)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. Sounds good to me. Done.